# What does "in the east" mean here?

Tags: prepositions, punctuation

I just read this sentence "when the wind was in the east a smell came across the harbour" from the Ernest Hemingway's novel *The Old Man And The Sea*:

Two questions:

1. What does "in" the wind mean? Does it mean the wind was "from" the east or the wind was "towards" the east?
2. Should there be a comma after the relative clause, before "a smell"?

Comment: When the wind was blustery in the east side of the harbour, don't know blowing at which direction, a smell came across the harbour.

Comment: As in [this old nursery rhyme](http://www.mamalisa.com/?t=hes&p=1828), a wind _in_ a <direction> means a wind _from_ that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it means "from the east". Winds are traditionally identified by the direction they come from (presumably since that determines their temperature, humidity, smell, etc.).
2. There's no relative clause here; "when the wind was in the east" is an adverbial clause. Personally I would prefer a comma after it, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: @user43947: You're welcome!